# MonoTouch .Net 4.0 Framework

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, xamarin.ios

I am creating a MonoTouch project and I need to use some properties that only exist in the .Net 3.0 (and higher) libraries, however MonoTouch creates a project with the 2.0 framework set by default. I have tried to look for a setting that I can change, I have cleanly installed MonoTouch 5.2 and I have even tried to change the schema attribute to 4.0 and nothing has worked. Does anyone have any advice or pointers on how I can do this? It should be simple, but I can't find anything anywhere. Also, I have looked at questions on SO about this issue but none of them have been of any help to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone have any advice or pointers on how I can do this?

**Short answer:** you cannot use **every** 4.0 features

**Long answer**

MonoTouch presently ships with a profile that is a superset of the Silverlight (aka 2.1) base class libraries (BCL). Part of the **super**set is that some new 4.0 features are also available. See the [documentation web site](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/) to see what's currently available.

However most of the new 4.0 BCL will only be available once MonoTouch is rebased on (the upcoming) Mono 2.12. Until then MonoTouch is using Mono 2.10 (current stable release) as it's foundation and the number of 4.0 features available is a bit limited.

So it's possible that some of the things you like to use is already present in MonoTouch. It's also possible that you can reuse some 4.0 code directly from the Mono source (very easy in some case, next to impossible in other cases). Otherwise you'll need to wait for the 4.0-enabled MonoTouch version later this year.

Comment: Any idea why I can't use System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader, even though it is listed in the documentation?

Comment: Did you add a reference to the `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll` assembly ? IOW this type is not located inside `System.Xml.dll` as it's namespace might suggest.

Comment: I noticed that and did try adding that reference but it still doesn't work.